# IIS-10 configuration for url rewrite on windows server-2016

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have url `abc.com/process/login`, so how to check is this `"process"` word present after`.com/` using regular expression url pattern?

I do have scenarios `abc.com/image/think/process/depth`, `abc.com/image/think/process_image/depth`, `abc.com/process_url/machine/code`. Then it shouldn't rewrite as `"process"` word not present next to `.com/`

So rewrite the url only if `"process"` word present next to `.com/`

```
example:  abc.com/process/login , abc.com/process/signup etc..
```

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this matching rule:

[image]

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test">
                    <match url="abc.com/process/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="URL address you rewrite" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```